# Implementing Webview to get text wrapping around an imageview

Tags: android

I've been researching and was surprised to find out that there was no text wrapping feature. However, I did see many suggest that webview might be an option to display such a thing. I've used webview to load a url, but how would I use it to display a body of text and image that is retrieved from a web service from within the app.

I make a call to the web service, I get the information, then I want to display it. Keep in mind only the top of my activity will have the text and image, so below the webView i'd want to implement some accordian style list view and a view page image gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is HTML land.

```
    <img align="left" src="[whatever]"/> Put your text here.  It should wrap 
around your image when it gets to the end.  I know somebody will freak and 
post the appropriate CSS for this, but whatever.  This should work.
```

Load that into your web view.  For referencing the image, you have two basic options.  Put the remote URL in the source (this may be very difficult), or save it locally and use "file:///[path to file]".

Comment: Why would it be difficult to get the remote url in the source?